# Post request to REST API & firebase not working from Flutter app

Tags: flutter, rest, firebase-realtime-database, flask-restful

I am trying to create a sign up page in flutter which submits to a firebase database through a REST API. I get an XMLHttpRequest error and 404 status code when i click the submit button, and I can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  // static const url = 'https://your-api-endpoint-url.com';

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  // Initialized date selector
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime(2002, 5, 10);

  final _signUpForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // Define the text editing controllers for the form fields
  final TextEditingController _studentIdController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = picked;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _submitForm() async {
    // Send a POST request to your REST API endpoint with the form data
    final url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      'userId': _studentIdController.text,
      'username': _nameController.text,
      'email': _emailController.text,
      'dob': _selectedDate.toIso8601String(),
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Handle successful form submission
      print('Form submitted successfully!');
    } else {
      // Handle form submission failure
      print('Failed to submit form.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Date Formatter
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
    final TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController(
        text: _selectedDate == null ? '' : formatter.format(_selectedDate));

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(350, 80, 350, 80),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
                key: _signUpForm,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: _studentIdController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Student ID Number',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: _nameController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Name',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 20),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: _emailController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Email',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Flexible(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              _selectDate(context);
                            },
                            child: AbsorbPointer(
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Date of Birth',
                                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                                ),
                                controller: _dateController,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 20),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 40, width: 50),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_signUpForm.currentState!.validate()) {
                          _submitForm();
                        }
                      },
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        fixedSize:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all(const Size(200, 50)),
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 56, 190)),
                      ),
                      child: const Text('Sign up'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I thought the issue was with the names i have given to the controller texts in the "response" method, so i changed them to match with the names of the fields in my firebase collection. However, i still had an error. Here's my API endpoint anf unction to add user:

```
@functions_framework.http
def run_app(request):
      # Check the request method
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'userId' in request.get_json():
      # Call the register_user function
      return register_user()
    elif request.method == 'GET' and 'userId' in request.args:
      # Call the view_user function
      return view_user()

def register_user():
    try:
        if not request.data:
            return jsonify({"error": "Request body is empty"}), 400
        record = json.loads(request.data)
        user_ref = db.collection("users").document(record["userId"])
        user = user_ref.get()
        if user.exists:
            return jsonify({"error": "User already exists"}), 400

        else:
            db.collection("users").document(record["userId"]).set(record)
            db.collection("users").document(record["userId"]).update({"posts": []})
            return jsonify({"success": "User successfully added!"}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An Error Occurred: {e}"
```